# Pyspark get the wrong date when importing from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to work with a dataframe populated from MongoDB in pyspark, but the dates I get are offseted by 1 day before. The field in Mongo look like this `fechaEnvio 2022-11-03T00:00:00.000+00:00`

But when reading in spark it look like this: `2022-11-02 21:00:00`

This is the schema for the collection I'm using:

```
camp_schema = StructType([
StructField("idCampana", StringType(), True),
StructField("fechaEnvio", DateType(), True),
StructField("fechaInicio", DateType(), True),
StructField("error", StringType(), True),
])
```

And this is the connection string:

```
campaigns_source = spark.read.format("mongo").option("uri", mongo_str.get_read_str('campanas')).option("schema", camp_schema).load()
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like timezone issue, can you check the same?

Comment: adding ```set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')``` in the configuration solved the problem! thanks

Comment: Should I add it as the official answer for future reference?